# Is pip 22.1.2 compatible with python 3.7.11

Tags: python, pip

I have got python 3.7.11 installed on my server, The client asks if I can have pip 22.1.2 with the python 3.7.11 version?

Is pip 22.1.2 even compatible with 3.7.11 ?

Comment: Have you tried it? What / who is “the client”?

Comment: My local installation: `$ python3.7 -m pip --version` -> 
pip 22.1.2 from /home/phd/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip (python 3.7). No problem.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's compatible ([https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/installation/#:~:text=Compatibility,3.9%2C%203.10%20and%20latest%20PyPy3.](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/installation/#:%7E:text=Compatibility,3.9%2C%203.10%20and%20latest%20PyPy3.))

The current version (v22.2) of pip works on:

- Windows, Linux and MacOS.
- CPython 3.7, 3.8, 3.9, 3.10 and latest PyPy3.

Comment: The question is about `pip` 22.1, not 22.2.

Answer (score 0):

[`pip` 22.1](https://pypi.org/project/pip/22.1/) requires Python >= 3.7. So yes, it's compatible. To up/down-grade:

```
python3.7 -m pip install --upgrade pip==22.1.2
```